# Xamarin.Forms C# String Formatting

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am fairly new to this language. Anyway, I am making a program that takes a text input of a DNA codon sequence and returns the amino acids. Basically I need to somehow take a string (say "ATC"), and convert it to "UAG. Any help?

Comment: There must be some folks here who know what algorithm (?) is implied by "ATC" -> "UAG", but to most of us it might as well be a knock knock joke in Linear B. You'll get more and better answers if you fill in the domain-specific parts: Explain the logic you're trying to implement, and ask for help with the implementation.

Comment: `if (myString == "ATC") myString = "UAG";` ? Very unclear what you actually need, how it relates to "String Formatting" (presumably you want to use `String.Format` somehow) and why it is specific to Xamarin (if you need help porting *your* solution from WinForm for example  make sure to provide sample and exact problem).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the string function replace https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically you can do something like:

```
string dnaamino = dnacodon.Replace("ATC","UAG");
```